# How to get BreezeJS metadata working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm getting this error with Breeze when I try to access the metadata url:

```
http://localhost:1886/api/posts/metadata
```

Self referencing loop detected for property 'PreviousAttribute' with type 'System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute'. Path 'root.firstAttribute.nextAttribute.nextAttribute.nextAttribute.nextAttribute.nextAttribute.nextAttribute'.
ExceptionType: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"

My other URL is working and retrieving data from the database just fine

```
http://localhost:1886/api/Posts/posts
```

My post.cs has nothing that could be self referencing and looks like so

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class PostsController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<PostsDbContext> contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<PostsDbContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts()
    {
        var posts = contextProvider.Context.Posts;
        return posts;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on Windows XP using Visual Studio 2010 and EF 4 and .net 4. Are there version issues with Breeze and any of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in my project must have become corrupt, because I started over with a clean HotTowel template and the problem magically went away

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that Entity Framework generates proxy objects. Try turning these of

```
dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I managed to get my hands on a Windows 7 machine at work and tried EF 5, but am still getting the same Self referencing loop error on the call to contextProvider.Metadata()